# why plot is not shown properly in Mac when using rpy2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpy2

I'm trying to make R plot in Python via rpy2 in Mac, but the plot is not shown up completely or python crashes after I close the window.

If I run the codes below ***without*** `r.quartz()`, there will be no graph at all but there is a pdf file named 'Rplot' generated in my folder which cannot be opened.

If I run the codes below ***with*** `r.quartz()`, plot will show up but python will quit unexpectedly after I close the graph window. I tried the codes in Windows and they work well.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

r = robjects.r

x = robjects.IntVector(range(10))

y = r.rnorm(10)

r.quartz()

r.layout(r.matrix(robjects.IntVector([1,2,3,2]), nrow=2, ncol=2))

r.plot(r.runif(10), y, xlab="runif", ylab="foo/bar", col="red")
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your local R settings, by default R might create a PDF graphical devices (for more information about graphical devices in the context of rpy2, see the doc: 
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.1.x/html/graphics.html#graphical-devices).

Regarding Python terminating, are you using Python interactively or you are running a script (e.g., `python myscript.py`) ? If the latter, it would be normal for Python to exit after the script reached the end of its execution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I run the codes in Spyder. If I run the script in Terminal then nothing will happen. It looks like something goes wrong when I call quartz device in rpy2. If I use quartz in R then everything goes fine... BTW the PDF created is damaged and cannot be open

Comment: I don't have an OSX system for rpy2 development/testing. I can't tell what is happening beside that it is working fine on Linux with X11 (quartz is specific to OS X, I believe). May be someone else here will have more insights.